# Iterating over a subrange of e.g.a vector?

Tags: c++

Is there a clean, modern C++ way to express e.g.:

```
double a[N];

for(int i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i)
   // Do something with a[i];
```

There are similar questions, one downvoted and the other using old C++, using non-standard libraries. I'm particularly interested in getting a grip on ranges and similar constructs.

Comment: `for (auto it = std::begin(a) + 1; it != std::end(a) - n; ++it) { ... }`? More C++-ish, but perhaps not "clean". So instead create a function that does the loop, and pass the start and end iterator to it.

Comment: And if your compiler is new enough, perhaps use [the ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)? Or [the range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) the standard is based on.

Comment: What is `n` in the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Using iterators directly

```
std::vector<double> a(N);
for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = std::next(a.begin(), 1);
     it != std::prev(a.end(), 1);
     ++it) {
  double d = *it;
}
```

Using a `std::span` that is like a view into your subrange, then you can use a range-based for loop

```
std::vector<double> a(N);
for (double d : std::span(a).subspan(1, a.size() - 2)) {
  // directly use d
}
```

Comment: `n - 1` in the loop does not point to N - 1 element.

Comment: Why spell out the iterator type, vs. just `auto it = std::next(a.begin(), 1);`?

Comment: You could just do `std::span(a).subspan(1, a.size() - 2)` and save a bunch of iterator manipulation.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my answer to use that version as its much more concise